# HTML keeping text spaced from left margin while zooming

Tags: html, text, margin, center

Does anyone know how to do this.  Using just HTML I have my body margins set to 300px left and right.

Now I want to keep the text about 300px out from the left margin so that when I zoom out it stays that far away from the left margin but still floats to the left.

edited: Question needed to be rephrased.

---

Answer: You guys thanks a lot for all your help I really appreciate it. After getting some responses and rethinking things I have researched something that will work. I am going to go with this.

I am now using:

```
<body background="image url" leftmargin="300px">

<p style="margin-left: 355px;"> My Header goes here </p>

Text for rest of page goes here.
```

Comment: Do you mean `text-align: center` (in CSS)?

Comment: I'm not really sure about CSS because I haven't done much of it. Basically everything on my page is mostly left aligned, but if I put my Header at 600px from the left and everything else at 300px from the left it makes the Header appear to be farther out.  And I'm trying to figure out how to do that.

Comment: You should use the style attribute: `<body style="background: url(image_url); margin-left: 300px">`, the background and leftamrgin attributes are deprecated.

Comment: Your question (and "answer") is still confusing. BTW, there is no attribute `leftmargin` in HTML. (And don't say "it works", because that's just because you are lucky).

Answer (score 1):

you can use this :

```
<div id="mainContent" style=" margin:auto; width:1000px;text-align:center">
//your text
</div>
```

** you can change your margin and width as you like.

Comment: That's kind of close to what I want. Basically I am trying to make the body of the page have 300px left margin and the header to have 600px left margin.  That way when I zoom out the left aligned text will be at 300 px from left but my header to be at 600px from the left.